Let SVG span <header> on all screen sizes
I have a header with a background-image defined inline and I also use an SVG as an overlay. I use the BS 5.3 framework However, when I reduces screen size the SVG stops spanning the header from top to bottom.
As an alternative I used a linear-gradient with stops to mimic the SVG, but this resulted in the bands having sawtooth appearance.
Tus the overlay works great untill around 600px then the SVG leaved a gap between itself and the bottom of the header.
How can I let the SVG span the whole header from top to bottom whilst perverving its aspect ratio on all screen sizes?


:root {
  /*add some transparency */
  --mark-bg-light: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 84%, transparent 84%);
  --hero-mark: var(--mark-bg-light);
}

.hero-section {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 70vh;
}

mark.mark-hero {
  background: var(--hero-mark);
  padding: 0.5rem;
  animation: none;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  h1 .mark-hero {
    color: black;
  }
}

.band--header__image__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 2500px;
  transform: translateX(-70%);
  z-index: 0;
  background-size: cover;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="body--theme1">
  <header class="hero-section mb-3 d-flex align-items-center overflow-hidden position-relative" style="background-image:
         linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), 
         url('https://picsum.photos/1280/720.webp');">
    <div class="container-fluid z-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
          <h1 class="py-3" data-sal="slide-up" data-sal-easing="ease-out" data-sal-duration="750">
            <mark class="mark-hero">Hero Section<br>Background-Image<br>
                <span class="fw-light">Inline</span> 
                <span class="fst-italic">CSS</span>
              </mark>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="band--header__image__overlay">
      <svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 1475 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill="blue" d="M0 0h1101.85L815.1 1000H0z"></path>
                    <path fill="green" d="M814.32 1000L1101.07 0h187.25l-286.74 1000z"></path>
                    <path fill="yellow" d="M1000.96 1000L1287.71 0h187.25l-286.74 1000z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
        <!--================= DO NOT EDIT CODE ABOVE THIS LINE =================-->
        <hr>
        <p class="lead">DMollit anim commodo consequat cillum eiusmod commodo ipsum sit ut occaecat pariatur tempor. Excepteur sint laboris aliquip quis enim. Cillum dolor eiusmod elit reprehenderit proident nulla velit dolor velit enim sit. Do reprehenderit commodo
          ut officia eu in dolore consequat amet consequat nisi adipisicing nisi nisi. Est id magna incididunt incididunt in eiusmod amet anim velit culpa duis eu. Eiusmod id reprehenderit enim esse dolor in aliqua. Ex nisi mollit esse est minim enim
          sunt est quis do ipsum ipsum.</p>
        <hr>
        <h2>Sint fugiat</h2>
        <p>Ullamco consequat minim in ullamco anim dolor amet commodo labore sit reprehenderit elit minim ullamco. Esse ea id Lorem amet in tempor. Lorem adipisicing sint enim esse officia culpa.</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
          <li>Vestibulum vel turpis sit amet lorem convallis pharetra.</li>
          <li>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem.</li>
          <li>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit.</li>
          <li>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Magna sint est aute culpa excepteur nisi quis quis adipisicing fugiat consectetur deserunt magna voluptate. Sunt eu consequat aliquip enim elit dolore deserunt ullamco esse quis. Sunt ut elit duis consectetur fugiat non nisi. Excepteur dolor id
          reprehenderit ipsum. Aliqua veniam est ad Lorem in ad. Consequat irure sit est irure veniam. Minim exercitation labore ex mollit aliqua anim Lorem adipisicing fugiat nulla.</p>
        <hr>
        <h2>Eu incididunt</h2>
        <p>Do duis id duis veniam occaecat non mollit cupidatat consequat ad. Lorem consectetur labore sunt sint Lorem et mollit nostrud culpa reprehenderit est. Cupidatat Lorem mollit sit eiusmod quis amet nostrud nulla do sit quis ea ullamco duis. Aliquip
          aute pariatur fugiat irure ullamco anim magna irure nulla. Cupidatat dolore ex adipisicing dolore et ipsum ullamco deserunt mollit laborum sit officia. Culpa commodo eiusmod consequat non deserunt exercitation voluptate labore quis magna laborum
          exercitation. Irure tempor reprehenderit incididunt duis excepteur consequat anim nostrud magna.</p>
        <h3>Occaecat proident</h3>
        <p>Tempor eu pariatur ipsum ex. Laboris proident quis magna esse consectetur consectetur minim non velit aliquip consectetur aliqua aliquip laborum. Est aliquip quis commodo ut nostrud dolor sunt pariatur sunt culpa.</p>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




You mean .mb-3 { margin-bottom: 1rem !important; }?

Indeed, it's a BS5 class.

That is the culprit as far as I can see

Unfortunately not, as I adds a mrgin-bottom below the header element and not below the SVG:. Tus removing the class mb-3 still results in the same phenomenon.

Ok, too bad. It shows up quite prominently when inspecting

The SVG image simply isn't high enough. It's  1475 by 1000 pixels and you force it to fit the space you leave for it by using width: 100%; height: 100%;.

Try adding preserveAspectRatio="none" for the SVG and give the svg a size like width:50vw; height:70vh. The preserveAspectRatio="none" will force NONuniform scaling but I think this is what you want. Alternatively instead of  you can use a css gradient

@KIKOSoftware   Yes, but changing the viewbox and paths to make to SVG larger still produces the same problem, unfortunately
